# C/C++ executable on 32-bit and 64-bit machines

Tags: c++, executable, cpu-architecture

Is it possible to make an `executable` using *c/c++* that can run on both `32-bit` and `64-bit` machines? If so, how can I make one?

Comment: Note that there isn't any such language as "C/C++". You either have C, or you have C++, and they are two very different languages.

Comment: what platform are you targeting?

Comment: windows, sorry i forgot to write it there...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Correct but not really relevant - the relevant property here is a shared ABI between 32 and 64 bit systems, which is not assumed by C or C++.

Comment: @DunsanAntol: The mention of Windows should go into the question itself.

Comment: Why do you ask, and why can't you deliver both 32 bits and 64 bits separate executables? You really should **edit your question** to improve it, otherwise it is too broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, build a 32 bit executable. It can run on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: It requires that the operating system supports 32-bit executable. Like 32-bit libraries or WOW64 (Windows).

Comment: Yeah, but since OP didn't give any information about OS or other requirement, I assumed he wanted to build a Windows app.

Comment: @Antwane: Why make that assumption?

Answer (score 4):

The general advice (as [answered by Antwane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50349528/841108)) is to build a 32 bits executable. It probably would run on a 64 bits machine, if the operating system allows that. This is the case on Linux, Windows and some versions of MacOSX (but you need to check). However, 32 bits executables generally use a 32 bits [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (read also about [x32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) on Linux) and cannot profit of the lot of RAM available today (because each 32 bits process would use no more than 4 gigabytes of virtual memory, and generally at most 3).

Some rare [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) accepted [fat binaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary), but they are out of fashion today.

You might code, in some operating system specific way, a script (e.g. a [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) on Unix, or a [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) script on Windows) or a wrapper which detects if the processor is 64 bits and then run a 64 bits executable.

You could ship both 32 bits and 64 bits variants of your executable (and leave your user to decide which one it would run).

You could consider publishing (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)) the [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) of your program with some [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) license and leave the burden of compilation to your user.

You might consider compiling your C++ code (perhaps using [Emscripten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emscripten)) to [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly) byte code and expect your user to run your thing into his browser. But that might not work easily (because WebAssembly adds many restrictions for sandboxing purposes, so you probably won't be able to use all the C++11 standard library in that case).

Answer (score 2):

32 bit executable work in 64 bit machines but In the case of windows some  win32 api may not work while running 32 bit application in 64 bit machines

Answer (score 1):

You can have `32` and `64` bit together in one package.

in *Linux* systems if the `5th` byte in the file is `1`, it's a `32-bit` binary. If it's 2, it's `64-bit`. For added sanity checking :

- If the first 5 bytes are 0x7f, `"ELF"`, `1`: it's a 32 bit ELF binary.
- If the first 5 bytes are 0x7f, `"ELF"`, `2`: it's a 64 bit ELF binary.
- Otherwise: it's inconclusive.

in *Windows* systems :

```
x86 : PE  L
x64 : PE  d†
```

Also you can confirm the file utility (e.g. from `cygwin`) will distinguish between `32-bit` and `64-bit` executables. They appear as follows :

```
32.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
64.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

Comment: Or just run `file /path/to/executable`, it will recognize and parse the ELF header.

Comment: Because I don't see what it brings to OP, and w.r.t. other answers. He told (in a comment) that he cared about Windows.